# Just upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04: desktop folders will now not open and the desktop regularly freezes up

Tags: 18.04, upgrade

Glad to be here and excited to be onboard 20.04, but it's not without issues. After the upgrade, I can't open folders on the desktop and the environment regularly freezes up on me, so I have to physically reboot via the chassis button as I can't do anything with my USB peripherals. What exactly happened here? I suspect things went wrong after I customized my desktop with the Gnome Tweaks application. Is there a quick fix to this?

GNOME Shell 3.36.1

```
description: VGA compatible controller
   product: GM206 [GeForce GTX 950]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
```

I tried: **grep -E 'gnome|Error|error' /var/log/syslog** but I have no idea what I should be looking for. I am not seeing anything obvious to me.

Thx for reading and all helpful replies.

/J

Comment: Upgrading rather than a fresh install is always risky, and especially early on, when the upgrade has not yet been opened to the general users. Could you not try a fresh install? Also document changes you did with Tweaks if you think this is relevant. Telling that you looked at the log but that you did not see anything obvious is irrelevant. Better provide the log in that case.

Comment: I upgraded after the official release, just two days ago.

Perhaps you might have a suggestion for better grep terms for a more useful result?

Comment: I would not know better grep terms. To be really clear what you understand by "upgrade": did you used the live USB/DVD to install the new version over the old one (i.e. using the installer, where the old one is erased), or did you upgrade "in place", i.e. without erasing the old system?